Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105 while using Selenium-chromedriver with Powershell
I am using selenium-chromedriver with Powershell to automate a website on two different Windows vurtual machines.
On one machine I get this error:
[5648:4300:0912/151844.598:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(147)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105

about 20 times in a row, every few minutes.
It doesn't seem to affect the access to the site elements or automation at all, but fills my console.

The host-process can resolve the above address manually.
For simply hiding it, I tried setting the loglevel with chromeoptions but because this is an error, it still apears.
As an actual solution, I tried adding explicit firewall rules, both on the machine itself and in Azure-NSG but no effect.

Both machines are Azure-hosted VMs, the one with the error is Win11 the other Win10.
Any ideas what could be the reason for this?

Looks like you are not finding the host stun.l.google.com.  Are you behind a firewall?  You can try using PS Test-Connection to see if there is a route to the server.  The machine may be in a different domain or have different Group Policy that is preventing the connection from completing.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/operating-system-security/network-security/windows-firewall/rules#outbound-rules-considerations

Thanks, but as I said, can resolve the address manually as well as ping the address, even from the same process, that hosts my script.

You may have proxy turned on.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529849/how-can-i-disable-proxy-via-powershell-when-modifying-registry-does-not-work

Good Idea, but no.

Could be port number is being blocked by virus checker or firewall.

does not look like it.

Found this : https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1b0c0qo/help_needed_with_selenium_script_error_handling/

When you write "can resolve the address manually as well as ping the address, even from the same process, that hosts my script" is this from Powershell?

yes, from the same host process, my script runs in. But from the console or another process as well. @ShirazBhaiji

@jdweng I dont see the relevance of your link. The problem hasn't been solved there either.

To summarize:

It works on Windows 10
It fails on Windows 11
On Windows 11 it works when running from Powershell

Since it works in Powershell on Windows 11, it is not a Powershell version, OS or Network problem.
What is left is the selenium-chromedriver.

Is there a different version of the driver between the machines?
Perhaps there is a difference in defaults between Win 10 and Win 11. Could you specify which dns server should be used


The driver is exactly the same. As both machines using the driver from the same cloud drive, it's not just the same version, it's literally the same driver file.
The odd thing is, I am using the script for months now, and the problem appeared only a few weeks ago.
Apart from the OS difference, I keep coming back to the network environment. The VMs are in different resource groups, with their own NSG and are in different countries.
But as it works from the command line, it does not seem to be that either.

And, I don't understand why it needs to resolve that address in the first place. The script obviously does not need it, as it runs perfectly fine.

Do you have anything else running on these machines? Video conferencing / VOIP or similar.

Nothing. Their sole purpose is to run automated tests on a website all day long.
Btw. the complete error message is this btw:
[4076:9896:0923/102344.235:ERROR:socket_manager.cc(147)] Failed to resolve address for stun.l.google.com., errorcode: -105

Is there a difference in how the automated tests are triggered on the machines?

No, its the same.
Btw. I would even be fine if I could just suppress the error, as it does not affect the function, just the output.

You could try adding it to the hosts file:
74.125.250.129 stun.l.google.com
Then it would just use that value and not try to look it up

This has oddly no effect either.

Try moving the Windows 11 VM to the same network/resource group as the Windows 10 machine. Then will be able to see if it is a network or a machine problem

I can't unfortunately. They belong to two different organisational units.
